# VSTS Git - Policy to restrict offensive/rude comments

Tags: azure-devops

We use VSTS Git and would like to create a policy/rule where we would like to stop commit/push containing rude/offensive languages (especially on front end assets).

Is there way to achieve this?

Comment: For git itself, there is no way to detect what's the rude/offensive languages, you should specify the certain words if commit comments contain. And for now, you can use commit-msg hook or pre-commit hook to detect the commit comments in local repos. And in future, when the server-side hooks are available, you can use pre-receive hook or pre-push hook to detect the commit comments.

Answer (score 1):

No. Trying to filter/detect profanity is a [clbuttic mistake.](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-) You'll end up with tons of false positives while simultaneously allowing clever attempts to circumvent the filter to slip right through.

At the end of the day, this is a problem of office culture and professionalism.